# How to make a custom collider that will deform with a skeleton in Godot

Tags: godot

I would like to make a collision detector for a mesh I have imported from blender. The mesh is parented to a skeleton, which I use to deform the mesh. I would like to attach a collider to it in order to implement physics. Instead of attaching a general shape collider like a cube or sphere to the mesh, I want it to be an accurate copy of the mesh itself. I've tried adding a Trimesh Static Body, which does make a collider the same shape as the mesh, however since it's static, it won't deform with a skeleton. Is there a way to generate a collider the same shape as a mesh that would deform with a skeleton and also stay with the mesh as it moves around?

Comment: If you have an `Skeleton` node, I believe you should use `PhysicalBone` nodes for its physics, not `StaticBody`. As far as I have been able to gather, you make the `PhysicalBone` children of the `Skeleton`, configure their `bone` and `joint` properties, and give them `Transform` matching the bone. I did try but could not make it work.

Comment: @Theraot I was also not able to get the `PhysicalBone` node to work, but I found a different node called `BoneAttachement` that worked (shown below in the answer). I could be wrong, but I think the `PhysicalBone` node is normally used for ragdoll simulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can make a collider the same shape as a skeleton / mesh that is deformed by a skeleton by using the `BoneAttachement` node, which is a subcategory of the `Spatial` class. By using this node, you can attach a primitive shape collider to each bone in your skeleton. This will result in a mostly accurate collider shape made up of many smaller colliders that will deform and stay with the skeleton.**

---

**Step 1:**

Add a `BoneAttachment` node as a child of the `Skeleton` node in your model. Set the bone name property to whatever bone you would like the collision shape to follow. After this is done, any nodes parented to this `BoneAttachment` node will copy the transform of the bone which it is set to.

---

**Step 2:**

Add either a `KinematicBody` or an `Area` node as a child of the `BoneAttachment` node. Don't add a `RigidBody`, because they're meant to be controlled by physics only, so this won't work if you add it.

- If you add a `KinematicBody` node, your collider won't be affected by physics, but other objects like a `RigidBody` will still collide and bounce off of it.
- If you add an `Area` node, your collider won't directly affect any physics objects that come into contact with it (objects will pass right through it), but you can write a script that will cause some effect to happen when objects contact it. For example, you could make it so that when an object enters the area, a force is applied to it and it gets pushed away.

---

**Step 3:**

Add a `CollisionShape` node as a child of whatever `PhysicsBody` you chose in the last step. Choose the shape and configure its transform so it copies the shape of the part of the mesh you are working on. Then, repeat these steps for each bone of the skeleton until you have an accurately shaped collider.